# dimension of subspace of a matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider $M_{16}(\mathbb{C})$. Let $V$ be the subspace of $M_{16}(\mathbb{C})$ consisting matrices of the form given by,
\begin{bmatrix}
X & 0 & Y & 0\\
0 & X& 0& Y \\
Z & 0 & A & 0 \\
0 & Z& 0 &A
\end{bmatrix}
where $X,Y,Z,A \in M_{4}(\mathbb{C})$ and $0$ is the $4 \times 4$ zero matrix. I would like to find the dimension of $V$. Is it isomorphic to $M_{8}(\mathbb{C})\subset M_{16}(\mathbb{C}) $?

Comment: $M_8$ is not a subset of $M_{16}$

Comment: You can write a basis for $X$ over $\Bbb C$ consisting of $128$ matrices (you don't need to actually write them down, but each will have $1$ in one entry and all zeros elsewhere). This answers the question of whether $X$ is isomorphic to $M_8(\Bbb C)$ by dimension count.

Comment: @dmtri not exactly as a subset. sitting diagonally is an option of inclusion. $A\mapsto diag(A,A)$

Comment: @pancini Sorry there was a mistake in my question. I have edited the question. Now it is clearly 64 dimensional right?

Comment: Yes, you have $4$ free parameters, each with $16$ degrees of freedom, so dimension $64$. (This is not really a proof, just the heuristics.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map
$$
  \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ) × \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ) × \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ) × \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ)
  \to
  V \,,
  \quad
  (X, Y, Z, A)
  \mapsto
  \begin{bmatrix}
    X & 0 & Y & 0 \\
    0 & X & 0 & Y \\
    Z & 0 & A & 0 \\
    0 & Z & 0 & A
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
is bijective and linear, and thus an isomorphism of vector spaces.
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
  \dim(V)
  &= \dim(\mathrm{M}_4(ℂ) × \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ) × \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ) × \mathrm{M}_4(ℂ)) \\
  &= \dim(\mathrm{M}_4(ℂ)) + \dim(\mathrm{M}_4(ℂ)) + \dim(\mathrm{M}_4(ℂ)) + \dim(\mathrm{M}_4(ℂ)) \\
  &= 16 + 16 + 16 + 16 \\
  &= 64 \,.
\end{align*}